# How to clean data in python for Special Characters through Regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

```
  Name    Id     Salary    Desgn
0 Mike   B1230    3000     Engg
1 John   !@#2     3000     !@#&
2 Lucy   B1230    3000     %@#B
3 @#@&   @#@&     @#@&     @#@&
4 snow   B1230    3000     Engg
5 Lily   #&-@    3000      Engg
```

Output:

```
  Name    Id     Salary    Desgn
0 Mike   B1230    3000     Engg
1 John   !@#2     3000     
2 Lucy   B1230    3000     %@#B
3 
4 snow   B1230    3000     Engg
5 Lily            3000     Engg
```

I was trying to clean data where if a cell contains pure special characters(without any numbers or alphabets) it will replace those value as a null value by Regular Expression.

Comment: Should `%@#B` be deleted too?

Comment: You should write what you have tried before.

Comment: `^\W*$` will match all strings which have only non word characters

Comment: Not number or alphabet `^[^0-9a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: Following on from what @Matthias has said - it looks like: `df.replace('^\W*$', '', regex=True)` might work in your case...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match text that doesn't contain at least one alphabet or number and replace it with empty string,

```
(?!\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*)(?<!\S)\S+\s*
```

Here this `(?!\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*)` negative look ahead rejects a token if it doesn't contain at least one alphabet or number, then `(?<!\S)` ensures the match doesn't start partially from a token that may have alphanumeric character just preceding to it and `\S+` matches that token and `\s*` at the end consumes trailing space(s) after the removed token as you posted in your expected output.

**[Check out this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GOujrO/2)**

Comment: This matches substrings with an alphanumeric character in the beginning or in the middle: For a string containing `!@33#&`, `#&` will be matched.

Comment: @jrook: Fair point. This can easily be fixed by using a negative look behind `(?<!\S)` in the regex. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern `r'\B([!@#%&-]+)\s'` and should work for the examples you provided (except for the `%@#B` because it contains a letter, contrary to the description you gave).
In python this would be:

```
import re
patt = r'\B([!@#%&-]+)\s'
re.sub(patt, '', your_string)
```

If using pandas you can use apply: `df['new_column'] = df['string_column'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(patt, '', x))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [solution](https://regex101.com/r/HTb1t8/5):

```
(?<!\S)[^\w\s]+(?!\S)
```

Using lookarounds, this regex matches exactly the unwanted strings. This might help preserve the formatting of the text (e.g replace each match with `"    "`.

The problem with `\W*` or `\W+` in this case is that it will match all non-word characters even if they are adjacent to word characters so we need to be a little more specific.

**EDIT:** `!\S` in negative lookarounds above cannot be replaced with a `\s` and positive lookarounds because `\s` does not match start and end of the string and it will lead to a more complex regex in order to to match patterns at start and end positions.

Comment: i think this regular expression will not work for special character with space... For Example '@#& 123,'.  '!@  #-. Mn'

Comment: @SamVamsi I just entered the expression in your comment and the selection seems correct to me. Words containing at least one non-special characters are not selected. Here: https://regex101.com/r/H8xjfS/2